# How to generate a receipt when Pay Later contribution is received

Tags: email, contributions, receipts

I am using a Contribution page to take payments for Memberships, and wish to use the 'Pay Later' option.  I can set this up and it records the contribution OK, and a administrator can record the Paymant when it arrives, thus actually starting the Membership.  However:

The system emails the user an Invoice when the Contribution page is completed, but I cannot get it to send a Receipt (or anything else) when the payment is confirmed.  Apart from anything else I want to (automatically) send an email at this point which will act as a membership card.

I have also tried the CiviRules extension, but can't find an appropriate combination of Trigger and Conditions to get the right result - i.e. only on Pay Later (Card payment generates a receipt immediately, fine), not if the administrator does the whole process off-line, and covering both initial Membership Payments and Renewals.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways of recording a pay later contribution

1. Find related contribution, click on more link and then record payment. Or on view contribution page click on 'Record payment link'. Fill in the details and tick 'send receipt' checkbox.
   [image]

[image]

2. Edit the contribution and change the status from pending to completed with 'send receipt' checkbox ticked.

Note: #1 is a new method for recording pay later payments and will be same in coming days however #2 will be removed in future.

Comment: How did I miss that checkbox??

Comment: The checkbox is only visible if the selected contact has email address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom code for that, `hook_civicrm_postProcess` can be used which will get fired whenever a form is submitted, you can limit functionality based on form name and contribution ID to send email through code.

Detail of hook use: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_postProcess/

Thanks